# copying custom class list to another list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have figured out (or at least it feels like I have figured out) a way to make a list of weapons without having to hardcode everything like I was last trying.

So I have got my custom class for a weapon specifying type name attribute etc.
I have created another script will show a list in Unity's inspector that I can keep adding weapons to and changing the values to what I see fit.

I also have a game manager script that is the route of everything to from player stats game state etc..

I want to have this list now transferred to the game manager as a new list in that script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
[System.Serializable]
public class GameManager {
    public static GameManager GM;
    public static int FileIndex;
    public static List<Weapons> WeaponM = new List<WeaponDB>();

    public PlayerData Player;
    public bool SaveEnabled;
    public bool IsPaused;

    public int TimeHour;
    public int TimeMinute;

    public GameManager(){
        Player = new PlayerData();
    }
}
```

that would be my game manager.  Would it not be as easy as typing

```
    public static List<Weapons> WeaponM = new List<WeaponDB>();
```

and have all the list entries stored in there copied over to the list entry in my gamemanager?

Here is my WeaponDB script so you can see and I have another script but it just sets all the different attributes.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections; 
public class WeaponDB : MonoBehaviour{
    public List<Weapons> Weapon;

    public WeaponDB(){

    }
    public WeaponDB(List<Weapons> wpl){

        Weapon = wpl;

    }


    void Start(){}

    void Update(){}
}
```

I am getting an error of

> CS0246 the type or namespacename "weaponsdb" could not be found"

Comment: This part is probably not compiling: You're declaring a List of type `Weapons` and then assigning a List of `WeaponDB`: `public static List<Weapons> WeaponM = new List<WeaponDB>();`

Comment: noticed that still no go though.. its not copying the data over.

Comment: Please note that the game engine uses the [unity3d] tag. The [unity] tag is reserved for Microsoft technology with the same name.